# Нужны ли запятые при уточнении обстоятельства места?

Tags: пунктуация

Пришел он в ЦКБА в 1966 г. (,) в отдел криогенной арматуры (,) уже имея опыт конструкторской работы на предприятии оборонной промышленности.

Или лучше перестроить предложение?

Пришел он в ЦКБА, в отдел криогенной арматуры, в 1966 г., уже имея опыт конструкторской работы на предприятии оборонной промышленности.

Answer (score 3):

Лучше перестроить предложение по вашему варианту, уточнение в исходном предложении не на месте и напоминает вставку.

Comment: А запятая после "арматуры" не лишняя?

Comment: Запятая нужна, это обособленное уточняющее обстоятельство, сужение значения, выделяется запятыми с двух сторон.